# Test .htaccess RedirectMatch rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to test RedirectMatch rules to see if I am using the syntax correctly, but can't find anywhere to do it online.

I know of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857516/online-mod-rewrite-testing-tool) with links to two different tools - but they only seem to be for RewriteRules - whereas I want to test RedirectMatch type rules.

Does anyone know of anything like this?

Cheers,
BH-Tech

Comment: Much easier to test it on a local Apache

Comment: Would that be using something like WampServer?

Comment: Yes WAMP will be good for this.

Comment: Thanks - I will try with WAMP. I was really hoping there would be an online tool for this though - the regex I want to test is much like that of RewriteRule, so I can't understand why I can't find something to help.